# How do I end `scanner.Scan` loop in console for golang?

Tags: go

I have two (or potentially more) lines of input that I would like the program to take. eg.

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

According to the official doc, using

```
for scanner.Scan() {
}
```

will cause infinite lines to be scan until it reach EOF or error, are there other functions that will take two lines of input instead?

Comment: Can't you just break the loop after two lines?

Comment: What if I want more than 2 lines?

Comment: @Kevin use a counter and break whenever you want?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Using the same method, you can break after any arbitrary number of lines.

Comment: If I don't know how many lines the user is inputting, how do I use a counter?

Comment: which package is this scanner from?

Comment: If you don't know how many lines, how do you intend the user to signal when they're done? If EOF is signaled via a closed pipe, then the scanner will break, otherwise keep reading until you have what you want and stop.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's traditional to end user input from stdin with an empty (zero length) line. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    snr := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    enter := "Enter a line of data:"
    for fmt.Println(enter); snr.Scan(); fmt.Println(enter) {
        line := snr.Text()
        if len(line) == 0 {
            break
        }
        fields := strings.Fields(line)
        fmt.Printf("Fields: %q\n", fields)
    }
    if err := snr.Err(); err != nil {
        if err != io.EOF {
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go run data.go
Enter a line of data:
1 2 3 4
Fields: ["1" "2" "3" "4"]
Enter a line of data:
5 6 7 8
Fields: ["5" "6" "7" "8"]
Enter a line of data:

$
```

Comment: This is really clear and helped me in the context of piping Stdin from a file. I am wondering about this context though, requesting user input, could that result in the scan hitting an `EOF` ? I suppose this is the safe way of doing it as no harm in handling it even if it never happens?

Answer (score 12):

Ask the user to press "CTRL + D", that signals the EOF from the terminal, your above code should work without any change.

Comment: fails in windows 10 cmd prompt

Comment: The answer I was looking for. @ama

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this is to verify if the scanner has reached the end of the file.

```
var s scanner.Scanner

   file, _ := os.Open("file.go") // return io.Reader

   s.Init(file) // needs io.Reader

   var character rune
   character = s.Scan()

   for character != scanner.EOF {
    // here your code
   }
```

Answer (score -3):

use ctl+z to end scanner.Scan()

Comment: the answer is meant to be programmatically

Comment: this will put it in the background, not end it. don't do this.